# Get comma-separated values three at a time

Tags: python, csv

So I have a text file with comma separated numbers, I'm trying to write Python to get me the numbers three at a time - they're 3D co-ordinates and I want to analyse them 3 at a time.

The text file is of the form

```
x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,...,
```

and is just one line.

Comment: One of the faster answers I've gotten. Thanks guys, still figuring my way with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Any comma separated data evinces the need for CSV but you could do with simple split here too.

Your comma separated string of (x, y, z) coordinates

```
>>> t = "x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3"
```

Use split :

```
>>> t1 = t.split(',')
>>> t1
['x1', 'y1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2', 'z2', 'x3', 'y3', 'z3']
```

Then collate / group the results into 3 elements. You will need to make sure that len(t1) is multiple of 3s. Use assert for that.

```
>>> t2 = []
>>> for x in range(len(t1)/3): t2.append(t1[x*3 : x*3+3])
... 
>>> t2
[['x1', 'y1', 'z1'], ['x2', 'y2', 'z2'], ['x3', 'y3', 'z3']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. Check out the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Comment: You should call it "the `csv` module", not "the CSV module", really.

Comment: If you are talking about the module names in being lower case, I meant CSV as in the format more than the name of the module.

Answer (score 2):

```
def coords(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    for i in range(0, len(parts), 3):
        yield map(int, parts[i:i+3])
```

No need to resort to regexes, really.

Comment: +1 for generator, and conversion to ints (although they might be floats)